# Why doesn't the Compose state only update UI component but also relaunch logic code in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

Before Compose, I use `LiveData` to connect between UI component and data, the UI component will be updated when the data of `LiveData` type has changed. After I use Compose, I was told that `MutableState<T>` is just like `LiveData`, but it is used in Compose.

In the following Code A, `val count` is `MutableState<T>` type in Part 1, so the text will be changed in Part 2 when I click the button in Part 3. The above procedure is easy to understand, just like I use LiveData before.

But `"3 times clicked"` will be displayed when I click the button for 3 times, I don't understand why Part 4 is launched, you know `if (count.value == 3)...` is a logic code and it's not associated with any UI  component.

1: Does it mean that the system will observe all code which are associated with `val count`, and run it automatically when the `count.value` is changed?

2: Will Part 5 always be relaunched when I click the button in Part 3 ?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun Counter() {

    Column {
        //Part 1
        val count = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

       //Part 2
        Text(
            text = "I've been clicked ${count.value} times",
        )

        //Part 3
        Button(onClick = { count.value++ }) {
            Text("Click me")
        }
       
        //Part 4       
        if (count.value == 3) {
            Log.e("My","This is test")
            Toast.makeText(LocalContext.current, "3 times clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        //Part 5
        Log.e("My","Is it always displayed?")
        Toast.makeText(LocalContext.current, "Is it always displayed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            BasicsCodelabTheme {
                Surface{
                    Counter()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Added Content**

In Code B, I know the Part A will be relaunched when the value of `displayFullItemByID` has changed.

1. Will Part B be relaunched when the value of `displayFullItemByID` has changed ?
2. Will Part C be relaunched when the value of `displayFullItemByID` has changed and it's equal to 5 ?

**Code B**

```
class VoiceAdapters (private val aHomeViewModel: HomeViewModel) {

     fun bind(inputMVoice: MVoice) {                        
           aHomeViewModel.displayFullItemByID.observe(mLifecycleOwner) {
                //Part A
                _isDisplayed.value = inputMVoice.id == it
            }
 
               //Part B
            Log.e("My","Can I relaunched in Part B")
            
            if (aHomeViewModel.displayFullItemByID.value==5) {
                //Part C
                Log.e("My","Can I relaunched in Part C") 
            }
    }

}

class HomeViewModel() : AndroidViewModel(mApplication) {
    private val _displayFullItemByID = MutableLiveData(-1)
    val displayFullItemByID: LiveData<Int> = _displayFullItemByID
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Toast` is an example of a [side-effect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) - something that affects the state of the device outside of the Composable itself (in this particular case, having the system show a toast message).

As per the documentation, compositions should be side-effect free - a core part of the [mental model](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model) is that the actual composition of a `@Composable` function could happen many, many times.

So yes, any reads of `count.value` will cause that composable function to recompose (i.e., be executed again). However, this probably isn't what you want in the case of a `Toast` message - you wouldn't want multiple toast messages, just the one when the value first changes to 3.

This is one of the use cases for [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect), which only runs its block when the input parameters change:

```
// This LaunchedEffect only runs when count.value changes,
// thus ensuring that only a single call to Toast.makeText()
// happens for each time the count changes to exactly 3
LaunchedEffect(count.value) {
    if (count.value == 3) {
        Toast.makeText(LocalContext.current, "3 times clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean the whole function `fun Counter()...` will be relaunched when the `count.value` is changed?

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: The `Counter` composable gets recomposed whenever any of the state changes - that's exactly what that mental model page I linked to talks about. Your added content has nothing to do with Compose, so it doesn't follow Compose's mental model - only the code within the `observe` call actually gets called when the value changes.

Comment: And just to keep things clear, if `count` is the only state variable then there is no problem with the code mentioned by HelloCW and there is no need for the `LaunchedEffect() `since while recomposition compiler considers the condition `count.value == 3` to display Toast. but in case if you have another state variable Y inside `Counter()` then assume after reaching `count.value`  to 3 if you start updating state variable Y then you start getting loads of toasts, at that time you need LaunchedEffect for sure. Am I right @ianhanniballake ? Or I understood it wrong?

Comment: @AgentP - that's not necessarily true, no. You should **never** assume that something will or will not recompose and should **always** use the various effects APIs for side effects. For example, any change to a value provided by a [`staticCompositionOf()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#staticCompositionLocalOf(kotlin.Function0)) will cause the entire tree to recompose, even if `count` hasn't changed (on place this happens is when using a `singleTop` operation in Navigation Compose or when using multiple back stacks).

Answer (score 1):

So let me start with the CODE A

> 1. Does it mean that the system will observe all code that is associated with val count, and run it automatically when the
>    count.value is changed?

**Answer**: If a compose has a local state variable then anytime the state variable is changed then the whole `@Composable` function gets reinvoked and recomposition happens. Regardless of whether it's logic code or UI code...

> 2: Will Part 5 always be relaunched when I click the button in Part 3?

**Answer**: Yes each time when there is a recomposition i.e in this case the change of count causes recomposition... then whole Counter() is called again and hence the part 5 is also called again and again

Coming to CODE B as mentioned by **ianhanniballake** it has nothing to do with the Compose and

> only the code within the observe call actually gets called when the
> value changes

### Other Important Things You Should Know :

You should understand how recomposition works actually from [Thinking In Compose Article](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#recomposition) because you got this question just because of lack of not knowing how recompose actually works...

one point about recomposition mentioned in that is

> Recomposition skips as many composable functions and lambdas as
> possible.

An example would be, consider this counter Composable()

```
    @Composable
    fun Counter() {
        Column {
            Column {
                val count = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
                Text(
                    text = "I've been clicked ${count.value} times",
                )
                Button(onClick = { count.value++ }) {
                    Text("Click me")
                }
                ShowText("")
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun ShowText(someText: String) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Show Text is Displayed")
        Text(someText)
    }
```

In the above composable function there is one more Compose() called ShowText().

Key things to understand in this example code is ...

- When the count value updates the whole Counter() composable function reinvoked and recomposition takes place
- But, The ShowText() will not be recomposed since it doesn't depends on any state value/variable from Counter()